# "putting money in the bank" = idiom?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I came across the following text and I don’t understand what the second sentence means. "Chanda-Leah does a trick we all wish our dog could perform. It puts money in the bank."
Is "putting money in the bank" an idiom I am not familiar with? If yes, could anybody explain its meaning? If not, what do you think the writer was trying to say? I tried to google it, but without any success.

Comment: "Money in the bank", with several variations, is a sort of a metaphor.  Sometimes the "money" is literal, sometimes metaphorical.  "In the bank" simply means actually earned or otherwise generate, vs just a theoretical benefit.  In this case (absent any sort of context) I suspect it means that the dog earns real money somehow, perhaps as a performer.

Answer (score 1):

From the limited context available, here is how I'd interpret it. The sentence goes to say that Chanda-Leah's (maybe a two-person team's) actions are something that the speaker sarcastically wishes his dog could perform. But he goes on to say that the action puts money into the bank meaning that it provides money to the team. Firstly the author demeaningly refers to the actions as something suited for a dog to do (the author doesn't say that it is something he wish he could do). The word 'trick' also help to convey that meaning. And he goes on to say that "perform"ing such a "trick" puts money in the bank suggesting income generation.

Answer (score 0):

To "put money in the bank", or "the money's in the bank", is like having confidence in something or counting on something to happen. EXAMPLE: "I would not bank on that invention ever working", meaning, "I do not have confidence in that invention ever working". Although I have no frame of reference with whatever it is that you are reading, out of context it seems literal. The dog's trick wins contests and competitions for the owner, therefore the money earned goes into the bank.